# Get form values in Symfony2 controller , Child does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

This is how the source code of input username is :

```
<input type="text" id="user_username" name="user[username]" >
```

When I try to get it in the controller I get this error :

```
Child "username" does not exist
```

Controllor :

```
//.......
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $i = 0;
        $username = $form["username"]->getData();
        $user= $em->getRepository('UsersBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($username);

//.......
}
```

This is th formType

```
class EleveType extends AbstractType
{
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder
        ->add('user', new UserType())
        ->add('ecole')
        ->add('niveauscolaire')

    ;
}
```

Comment: how do you create the form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
$username = $form["username"]->getData();
```

with

```
$username = $form["user"]["username"]->getData();
```

Comment: ["user"] before ["username"]  thank you ;)

$username = $form["user"]["username"]->getData();

Comment: Indeed, that was a mistake :) Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to use:

```
$username = $form["user"]["username"]->getViewData();
```

instead of:

```
$username = $form["user"]["username"]->getData();
```

Thanks for @Jacob orientation which help me and sorry for my shinny english.

Answer (score 1):

If that:

```
$username = $form["user"]["username"]->getData();
```

doesn't work, you can use instead:

```
$username = $form['user']->getData()->getUsername();
```

*(tested in SF 4-5)*