# Child does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

Okay, this was asked, however, I tried what was given on stackoverflow. From what I understand, buildForm needs to be added. But still not working for me. I also read another answer to clear cache, that did not work either.
Error is `Child "someinput" does not exist.`

In my EntityType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('someinput', 'text',array('mapped'=>false))
    ;
}
```

Next, in my controller:

```
$en = new Model();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm();
$request = $this->get('request');
$form->handleRequest($request);            
if($request->getMethod()=='POST'){
    $input_value = $form->get("someinput")->getData();
...}
```

View:
I tried:

```
{{form_start(form)}}
    {{form_widget(form)}}
{{form_end(form)}}
```

Also tried:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="someinput" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

And tried:

```
{{form_start(form)}}
    {{form_row(form.someinput)}}
{{form_end(form)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create the form first:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ModelFormType());
```

`ModelFormType` is your form type class where you added `someinput` text field.

Comment: im having the same problem.

Comment: @JamAndJammies : Have you read this article? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545929/get-form-values-in-symfony2-controller-child-does-not-exist